# Getting processor type in Linux using C

Tags: c, linux

I am trying to get the systems processor type, number of processors, and max number of open files per process in Linux using C. I found that

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/sysinfo.h>
int main()
{
   printf("There are %d processors.\n", get_nprocs());
}
```

gives me number of processors. Is there a way to access the other 2 desired features using sysinfo?

Comment: Read `/proc/cpuinfo`

Comment: how do I access using the C language though? Sorry I am brand new to both C and Linux. trying to learn. @Barmar

Comment: You need to read a tutorial on reading files in C. This isn't a tutoring service.

Comment: It's Linux: everything is a file. Just find the file name and read it (with fopen(), fread(), etc.) /proc/cpuinfo is a good start. Also lots of stuff in /sys/devices, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much. @LeeDanielCrocker

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, you are undoubtedly expected to use `uname()` and `getrlimit()` instead of reading `/proc`